# host static files (images) to 3rd party host such as Amazon Cloud. Any modules can facilitate this?

Tags: cdn

I want host all images files to the cloud, such as amazon s3.

For example, when creating the node, uploaded automatically upload the files to the cloud, and all images path automatically point to the image stored in the cloud.

Any modules facilitate the CDN transition?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with the [CDN](http://drupal.org/project/cdn) module, also checkout the [AmazonS3](http://drupal.org/project/AmazonS3) module.

Comment: but it seems that it won't upload(sync) the files to CDN site automatically.

Comment: Check out the description from the AmazonS3 module for example: "Image styles are delivered first through the private file system, which generates a derivative on S3 and is served from S3 thereafter."

Comment: The CDN module also allows syncing but you need to use File conveyor: http://fileconveyor.org/

Comment: there are issues with image resizing when using S3:  http://drupal.org/node/1291628

Comment: tried CDN module with File Conveyor method, it works but buggy with D7, for example, the ftp username cannot contain "/".

Comment: I've used the CDN module with File conveyor and its worked perfectly for me, of course it won't work perfectly in every setup. Try using another transfer protocol.

Comment: How do you rewrite URL to point to cdn?

Answer (score 1):

[Media Mover](http://drupal.org/project/media_mover) supports staging/moving files to Amazon S3, plus complex file workflows.

Answer (score 1):

[Drupal CDN & Static File Server - The Amazon S3 Way](http://www.slayerment.com/blog/drupal-cdn-file-server-amazon-s3-way) is an oldie but a goodie as well

Comment: Also, you may also want to look into the "s3fs" concept where you mount your s3 bucket as a filesystem on your server...linux based anyway.

Comment: make sure to check with your hosting provider if that's supported. We tried that on Pantheon, got it to work but found out later that it broke the daily backup routine.